# How does `plot_surface` from mplot3 use its first two 2-dimensional parameters?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Looking for a way to plot a function `z=f(x,y)` with mplot3d, I found https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots where the first example looks just right.

Looking at the parameters of `plot_surface(X, Y, Z)` all three of them need to be like-sized **2**-dimensional arrays.

I see why `Z` should be 2-dimensional, but why `X` and `Y`? I thought I just don't understand what a "surface plot" is, but all non-matplotlib references I found use 1-dimensional arrays for the first two parameters. How are the 2-dimensional `X` and `Y` used?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain in words. The `plot_surface(X, Y, Z)` generates a 3-d figure. Now, assume we have a 2-d (x-y) grid of 10x10 = 100 points where the x goes from 1 to 10 and y goes from 1 to 10. Now overall there are 100 pairs of (x,y) as (1,1), (1,2), (1,3) ... (1,10), (2,1), (2,2)....(2,10).... (10, 1), (10,2)...(10,10).

Now for each of this (x,y) pair, you define a corresponding z-value. That means in total, for 100 (x,y) pairs, you have total 100 z-values. If you just use `X=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` and `Y=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` then you basically want to give the X-coordinates for all those 100 points. Since each Y-value is sharing the same X-coordinates, these 10 X-values will repeat 10 times (because you have 10 Y-values). Hence you create a mesh-grid of 100 X values. Same applies to the Y so you have a mesh-grid of 100 Y-values. Having these 100 pairs of (x,y) generated from the meshgrid, and having 100 Z-values, you just use `plot_surface(X, Y, Z)`.